# How to upload to drive and return back url to save to google sheet using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am looking for developing something like this : 
[Final Form Example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxlX3r_dt_ZLZC9TqloaqtdextROJoIH9mUDu3MWOiXtI6ADhqb/exec)

Currently my form looks like this : 
[Current Form](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzF9LDL-BmARktCNoV_qfB2JxBc3N2Z1Y42NlWoQ8I/dev)

I'm able to save values into spread sheet. But the [documentation as given by google here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) is not that clear on how to start consuming a service from scratch.

My current scripts look like :

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms.html').setTitle("Unifoil Purchase Order Update");
}
function saveDataInSheet(url, name, email, comments ) {
   try { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sdjghsdhgkshdksdhzxnvlsdhgls-i7w/edit");

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master Purchase Head');

  var dates = new Date();
  if(comments == ""){
    comments = " ";
  }
  sheet.appendRow([dates, name, email, comments, url ]);  
      return "OK";
  } catch (f) {
  console.log(f.toString())
    return f.toString();

  }

}

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, name, email, comments) {

  try {

    var po_folder = "Purchase Order Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(po_folder);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(po_folder);
    }

    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file),
        file = folder.createFolder([name, email].join(" ")).createFile(blob);

    var url_of_saved_file = file.getUrl();  
    saveDataInSheet(url_of_saved_file, name, email, comments );
    return "OK";

  } catch (f) {
    return f.toString();
  }

}
```

As you can see currently the sheet url and names are hardcoded. 
Also I had to create the initial sheet on the drive before. 
Any way I could create sheets on the fly, return url from the drive where its uploaded, open that and edit it. 
Also if any pointers on creating charts on the spreadsheet through data submitted on form ? (Not filling columns to which pre defined charts are linked, but letting the user choose and create new charts)

Comment: what do you want to do instead of hardcoding? Create a new one?

Comment: I mean yes, what should be the correct approach, some kind of check for creating a new sheet if doesnt exist, else append to previously created sheet

Comment: And do you want to create a new [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String)) or a new [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String))? Both are documented.